# Android. Automatically closing second activity in a minute after app goes to background

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose my android app has two activities A and B. Activity A starts activity B (A->B). When activity B is shown a user presses "Home" button and the application goes to background. Now I want activity B to be closed automatically in background (because it has some secret information displayed), say, in a minute after the user pressed "Home" button. Which is the best way to implement this?

I tried to do it using Handler and postDelayed() placed in onStop() of activity B, but it seems like it sometimes doesn't work and activity B stays not finished when the app is resumed from backround...

My code is:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mLockHandler = new Handler();
    mLockRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
    };
    mLockHandler.postDelayed(mLockRunnable, 60 * 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Android is able to finish activity by itself when it doesn't have enough resources.

If that happened, I suppose the handler is not available as well. If you very want to handle your activity finishing, you need to create some class, which will survive during activity lifecycle(AKA Singleton). That wouldn't let android to remove it from memory. 

Although you would have another couple problems:

Your singleton won't be able to finish activity if it is in a wrong state. 

Putting activity to singleton will lead to memory leak.

Summarising, trying to change activity lifecycle is a bad idea. Maybe some `Service` class will solve your task in background?